# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getsubcategory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I am trying to access the 8coupons api since i want to learn angularjs. But, whenever i try to hit the url it displays XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getsubcategory. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

javascript:

```
var getjson = angular.module('dataapp',[]);
getjson.controller('controller',function($scope,$http)
{
var url = "http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getsubcategory?key=62a3ce5309039c70b7e74e759d0092282a50558b7af45ae1ca8c4bb1fa6bb4fcb16a7c896175dd5414746e2d407098dc"; 

$http.get(url).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    $scope.jsondata = data;
    console.log(data);      
}).error(function(data,status,headers,config){      
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `$http` request as follows.

```
  var url = "http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getsubcategory?key=62a3ce5309039c70b7e74e759d0092282a50558b7af45ae1ca8c4bb1fa6bb4fcb16a7c896175dd5414746e2d407098dc&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&time"+Math.random();

  $http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log("Success");
      console.log(data[0].category);
    }).error(function(data) {
      console.log("Error");
    });
```

Appended the additional param in the above URL which is required for `JSONP` call. Read the doc for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

> callback=JSON_CALLBACK

**Demo** : http://plnkr.co/edit/m9GW6y1JuiimbvKibQZ4

Answer (score 0):

I just added www.corsproxy.com as a prefix to the url domain

e.g., http://www.corsproxy.com/api.8coupons.com/.....

my problem got fixed